# Weird unhealthy errors on Elastic Beanstalk Worker environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I've seen some weird errors happening on my worker environments only (this never happens on the web environments).

I can see this in the "Health" page:
**Following services are not running: aws-sqsd.**
**clock out of sync...**
**Instance ELB health is not available**

Some screenshots:

[image: Following services are not running: aws-sqsd]

[image: clock out of sync]

[image: Instance ELB health is not available]

This last error I realized that when I create a new worker single environment, the instance is not attached to the Load Balancer and I have to do it manually. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Has anyone experienced something similar?